# Open preview in new window/page

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I'm using drupal 7.

Normally, during the creation of a contents, the preview is added above the form.

I would wish that the preview opens in a new window, and that it is separated from the form of creation of contents.

Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This module looks like something that might fit your need: [Simple preview](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_preview)